# Removing inline declarations makes code work. Why?

Tags: libgdx

This does not work:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() /Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
```

This does:

```
float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * (h/w));
```

I do not get the difference. One displays fine on my screen, the other remains black.

Why is this? Is there any syntactical reason why this does not work, or is it a bug?

Comment: "inline declaration" usually refers to a function declaration. What you're actually doing here is passing an integer expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're doing integer math in the first case, but not in the second.

First, a quick look at the documentation

> **getWidth**
>   `int getWidth()`
>    **Returns:**
>   the width in pixels of the display surface.
>   <
>
> ---
>
> **getHeight**
>   `int getHeight()`
>   **Returns:**
>   the height in pixels of the display surface

So now we know that the two methods return integer values (understandable - it's a count of pixels).  So when you execute this:

```
Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()
```

... it does the division, which for integers *truncates* the result ("rounds" towards 0).  And since screen widths are usually larger than heights...

```
1. Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth() = 
2. 1080 / 1980 = 
3. 0.545454545 = 
4. 0
```

... so you're really ending up with:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 0);
```

Fortunately, this fix is simple.  You can either keep the assignment to local `float` variables, like you do in your latter example, or you could just cast one of the returns:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(100, 100 * ((float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / Gdx.graphics.getWidth()));
```